# How do I generate a link that requests access to read non-public sheet using the google-drive api?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

My company is trying to get requests to access non-public user sheets. Here is how we want to go about it:

The user receives a link which contains all the necessary authentication information , and when they open the link, it gives them an alert saying something like "Grant client_id/client_email access to google_sheet"?,  and when they click "yes", we get access to read the dataset?

is something like this possible with the google-drive api  ?

I have looked at the google-sheet api [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) and the google-drive-sdk [here](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google-drive%20sdk) , but I have not found what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When your application requests non-public user data, it must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Check this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize). Requests to the Google Sheets API for non-public user data must be authorized by an authenticated user. The details of the authorization process, or "flow," for OAuth 2.0 vary somewhat depending on what kind of application you're writing. Check this [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize#perform_oauth_20).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually forgot to close this question because it is too vague, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094869/google-drive-api-nodejs-error-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes) is the more 'complete' question with code that I implemented

Comment: Sorry, the link is actually [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105853/unable-to-generate-url-to-send-to-user-for-requesting-access-to-a-particular-non)